# Recognize as a special function?

Tags: special-functions

Is the following function a special function of some kind
$$
f(x)
=
\int_0^x (1+e^{-t})^{b}\,dt,
$$
where $b>1$?

Comment: Yes, the integral is equal to $$\frac{2^{b+1}}{b} {}_2F_1 \left(1,1,1-b,-1 \right) - \frac{e^x (1+e^{-x})^{b+1}}{b} {}_2F_1 \left(1,1,1-b,-e^{x} \right),$$ where $_2F_1$ denotes Gauss hypergeometric function.

Answer (score 2):

If $b$ is integer, then you can use the binomial theorem to get

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^b  \binom{b}{k} \int_0^x e^{-kt} dt = \sum_{k=0}^b  \binom{b}{k} \frac{1}{k} (1-e^{-kx})$$

which isn't 'special' at all. If $b$ is non-integer then I don't know, but since argument $x$ of $f(x)$ is 'just' the upper integration bound, it doesn't seem like it's in the same league as exciting and well-known special functions like $\Gamma$ or $\zeta$.

You may also write
$$f(x) = \int_{e^{-x}}^{1} \frac{(1+u)^b}{u} du$$

which again does not hit me as anything special and probably isn't too hard to solve.

Comment: Thanks, that helps as well